# Display output with write for Fortran

Tags: fortran

I want to display an output with `Test = 0` using Fortran, I tried to use:

`'WRITE(11,*) 'Test =' testdata'`

Assuming 11 is correct and `testdata` is a parameter that is being calculated.

I wasn't able to get the output and there was an error.

Anyone have any idea why it is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try inserting a comma and deleting the apostrophes:

```
WRITE(11,*) 'Test =', testdata
```

If you had reported what the error message you saw was I might have made this answer more apposite.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the output with that! :)

Comment: Just one more question will be, if i want to display another data but on the same line, how will it be done? As in 'Test =', testdata, 'Test2 =', testdata2

Comment: @user1204868, just place futher data that you want to display on the same line (or within the same _record_ as per Fortran's terminology) in the `WRITE` statement, separated by commas. Keep in mind that code lines in Fortran cannot be arbitrary long as in some other languages.